# Pytest fixtures in requests post function

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to understand the example provided [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes) and emulate it to work for the `post` method instead of `get` method.

All works well when I'm testing for `response.status_code == 200`. How do I test for more than one response status codes without repeating the code (like in [here](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/monkeypatching-with-pytest/)?
I understand that one needs to use fixtures, how do I leverage them?

This is where I'm up to now.

```
app.py

from typing import Dict, Union
from urllib.error import HTTPError

import requests
import structlog

logger = structlog.get_logger()


def get_access_token(
    url: str, client_id: str, client_secret: str, grant_type: str
) -> Union[Dict[str, Union[str, int]], None]:
    try:
        r = requests.post(
            url,
            data={"grant_type": grant_type},
            auth=(client_id, client_secret),
            verify=True,
        )
        logger.info("Fetching token status code", status_code=r.status_code)
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        logger.error("HTTP error occurred", http_error=str(http_err))
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error("Other error occurred", exception=str(err))
    else:
        # The token expires in 10800 seconds
        return r.json()
```

```
test_app.py

# contents of test_app.py, a simple test for our API retrieval
from typing import Dict, Union

import pytest
import requests

from app import get_access_token


# custom class to be the mock return value of requests.post()
class MockResponse:
    status_code = 200
    raise_for_status = None

    @staticmethod
    def json() -> Dict[str, Union[str, int]]:
        return {
            'access_token': 'fake-access-token',
            'token_type': 'fake-token-type',
            'expires_in': 10800,
        }

@pytest.fixture
def mock_response(monkeypatch):
    """Requests.post() mocked to return json."""

    def mock_post(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse()

    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "post", mock_post)


# notice our test uses the custom fixture instead of monkeypatch directly
def test_get_access_token_success(mock_response) -> None:
    result = get_access_token(
        url="https://fakeurl",
        client_id="fake-client-id",
        client_secret="fake-client-secret",
        grant_type="fake-grant-type",
    )
    assert result['access_token'] == "fake-access-token"
    assert result['token_type'] == "fake-token-type"
```

rewrote app.py after @gold_cy's suggestion

```
from typing import Dict, Union

import requests
import structlog

logger = structlog.get_logger()


def get_access_token(
    url: str,
    client_id: str,
    client_secret: str,
    grant_type: str = 'client_credentials',
) -> Dict[str, Union[str, int]]:
    try:
        r = requests.post(
            url,
            data={"grant_type": grant_type},
            auth=(client_id, client_secret),
            verify=True,
        )
        logger.info("Fetching token status code", status_code=r.status_code)
        r.raise_for_status()
        if r.status_code == 200:
            # FIXME: The token expires in 10800 seconds
            return r.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logger.error("HTTP error", request=err.response.text)
        raise requests.HTTPError(err)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing your code too much and with the assumption of testing `status_code` in mind, you can have your fixture return a function that you can provide `status_code` and `raise_for_status` into, in order to initialize your `MockResponse` class. However, looking at your token code you don't appear to utilize `raise_for_status`.

```
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, status_code, raise_for_status):
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.raise_for_status = raise_for_status

    @staticmethod
    def json() -> Dict[str, Union[str, int]]:
        return {
            'access_token': 'fake-access-token',
            'token_type': 'fake-token-type',
            'expires_in': 10800,
        }

@pytest.fixture
def mock_response(monkeypatch):
    """Requests.post() mocked to return json."""
    def wrapper(status_code, raise_for_status=None):
        def mock_post(*args, **kwargs):
            return MockResponse(status_code, raise_for_status)

        monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "post", mock_post)

    return wrapper


def test_some_random_status_code(mock_response) -> None:
    mock_response(301)

    result = get_access_token(
        url="https://fakeurl",
        client_id="fake-client-id",
        client_secret="fake-client-secret",
        grant_type="fake-grant-type",
    )

    assert result['access_token'] == "fake-access-token"
```

---

```
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, hypothesis-6.48.1, mock-3.7.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 1 item                                                                                    

tests/test_manager.py 2022-07-11 07:13.35 [info     ] Fetching token status code     status_code=301
.

========================================= 1 passed in 0.04s =========================================
```

Comment: is there a better way to rewrite it?

Comment: try using `raise_for_status` in your actual token generation code to raise for the invalid status codes, if your code returns a `40x` without generating an error then your function will break since it assumes you got back `json` successfully. non `20x` status codes do not automatically raise errors in the `requests` library @tandem

Comment: Tried what you suggested, and now it states that 

```>           r.raise_for_status()
E           TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: if you are having issues that is a separate question at this point as I don't have details of what has changed

Comment: Updated the app script in the question :-) and used your test script

Comment: that means `r` is None, i.e your request returned nothing, that means you need to supply something in the tests in order to test that functionality, notice how I left the option in the test script to pass in values for `raise_for_status`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `response.status_code == 200` you can check just `response.ok`. If you want to check more statuses then you could check is it in valid range.

```
if response.status_code in range(200, 300):
    print("response status is 2xx")

if response.status_code in (200, 201):
    pass
```

Comment: that would still require me to write two `MockResponse` classes. that's not ideal at all..